# How validation gives error when wrong data is inserted. working on isValid() in symfony?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony4

Controller function:

```
public function new(Request $request)  
    {  
        $post = new Post();  
        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);     

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()){

        if($form->isValid()) {
            die('working');
        }
        else
        {
            die("error");
        }
    }

        return $this->render('post/index.html.twig',[
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

In config/validator/validation.yaml

```
App\Entity\post:  
    properties:  
        title:  
            - Length:  
                min: 2  
                max: 50  
                minMessage: 'Your first name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long'  
                maxMessage: 'Your first name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters'
```

Form Class:

```
class PostType extends AbstractType {  
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)  
    {  
        $builder  
            ->add('title',TextType::class,[  
                'attr' => [  
                    'placeholder' => 'Enter Title',  
                    'class' => 'Some Class',  
                ]  
            ])  
            ->add('description',TextareaType::class,[  
                'attr' => [  
                    'placeholder' => 'Enter Description',  
                    'class' => 'Some Class'  
                ]  
            ])  
            ->add('Save',SubmitType::class,[  
                'attr' => [  
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success'  
                ]  
            ])  
        ;
    }
```

I have also added

`validation: { enable_annotations: true }`   in config/packages/framework.yaml

Question:
I am inserting a single alphabet say 'z' in title. It should return validation error. isValid() should give false but it is giving true. Can anyone tell me how to use validation over here?

Comment: `App\Entity\post:` Tried with a `P`?

Comment: @JonStirling: Thanks, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`enable_annotations: true` means that you define validation constraints via annotations. Annotation looks like this:

```
class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank    // apply NotBlank validator
     */
    public $name;
}
```

In your code, you use validation rules, defined in `yaml` file, so it is defintely **not** annotations.

So, either **move validation rules to annotations**, or **remove** `enable_annotations:true`, leaving just

```
validation: { enabled: true }
```

Comment: performed your suggestion, but problem is still the same.

Comment: Clear cache and all this stuff.

Comment: problem still exists. isValid() return true all the time.

Comment: Update question with relevant changes.

Comment: got the solution, actually it a syntax error, was not using psr4 for entity name.